# ModuleNotFoundError inside a tests folder

Tags: python-3.x, testing, importerror, modulenotfounderror, nose2

Inside my `tests` directory, I have `subtest_helpers.py` and other test .py files. `subtest_helpers.py` has functions that I use within my test files. At the beginning of said test files, I have `import subtest_helpers as sh` but this gives me

```
nose2.loader.ModuleImportFailure
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subtest_helpers'
```

I went into vscode, made a separate directory, and did a similar process. To my surprise, `import file_1 as f1` works if I want to use functions from file_1 in file_2 and they are both in the same directory. So what am I doing wrong here? Not sure if it has to do with the fact that I am using nose2, a tests folder, or something completely different